# After Upgrade to Magento2.3.5 Braintree started giving error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

After upgrade from magento2.3.3 to 2.3.5. Braintree has started giving error

---

```
code: "PAYPAL_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_NOT_LINKED"
details: undefined
message: "A linked PayPal Sandbox account is required to use PayPal Checkout 
in Sandbox. See 
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go- 
live/#linked-paypal-testing for details on linking your PayPal sandbox with 
Braintree."
name: "BraintreeError"
type: "MERCHANT"
__proto__: Error
```

---

I am using the same account details with my other site and its working fine but in this Magento version it is giving error.
Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? Please share ;)

Comment: @Joao71 Yes, this was due to some braintree account configuration issue. I exactly don't remember the solution but we did some changes in the braintree configuration and paypal account configuration.